# How to access Controls name used on contentview in the listview ViewCell xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am reusing my content views(userControls) in the listview. I want to access the controls names used on that contentview and want to assign the values from the database to it. I am getting the ContentView but I am unable to access the controls.

*The content of ContentView:*
[image: The content of ContentView is attached in the file.]

I want to access those labels, buttons, editor used in contentview.